# Calculating the daily minimum balance

Tags: java, postgresql

Let's say I have a table named transaction with transaction_date, deposit, withdrawal fields.  There may or may not be transaction on a day but can have multiple transactions for each day.  So, what I need to do is given a date range, say December 1, 2010 to December 31, 2010, I need to figure out the minimum balance on each day.  Let's assume there are transactions before December 1, 2010 as well.  Is there anyone who can give me an idea on this one?

Thank you.

**Update** *With Example*

```
 tran_date   withdraw    deposit
2010-11-23       0.00      50.00
2010-12-10       0.00      50.00
2010-12-10       0.00     200.00
2010-12-12     100.00       0.00
2010-12-20       0.00      50.00
2010-12-20      70.00       0.00
2010-12-20       0.00      50.00
2010-12-20       0.00      50.00
2010-12-24     150.00       0.00
```

In above example, the minimum daily balance from *Dec 1* to *Dec 10* would be **50**.  On *Dec 10* there are two deposits totaling **70** but the minimum balance on that day would be **50** (carried over from previous day).

Now lets look at multiple transactions.

The carried over on *Dec 20* is **200**. The first deposit makes it **250**, the second one makes it **180**, the third one makes it **230** and the last transaction makes it **280**.  So, the minimum balance for that day would be **180** after withdrawing **70** on the second transaction of the day.  Is it possible to generate this using a query on PostgreSQL 8.4 or should I use another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit2**
This is a full example, including the (minimum) balance from the previous day (as far as I can tell with such a small set of data). It should run on 8.4.

I refactored the derived tables to use CTE (common table expression) to make it (hopefully) a bit more readable:

```
WITH days AS (
   -- generate a liste of possible dates spanning 
   -- the whole interval of the transactions
   SELECT min(tran_date) + generate_series(0, max(tran_date) - min(tran_date)) AS some_date
   FROM transaction
),
total_balance AS (
  -- Calculate the running totals for all transactions
  SELECT tran_id,
         days.some_date as tran_date, 
         deposit, 
         withdrawal,
         sum(deposit - withdrawal) 
             OVER (ORDER BY some_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as balance
  FROM days
   LEFT JOIN transaction t ON t.tran_date = days.some_date 
),
min_balance AS (
  -- calculate the minimum balance for each day 
  -- (the smalles balance will have a '1' in the column balance_rank)
  SELECT tran_id, 
         tran_date,
         rank() OVER (PARTITION BY tran_date ORDER BY balance) as balance_rank,
         balance
  FROM total_balance
)
-- Now get everything, including the balance for the previous day
SELECT tran_id,
       tran_date,
       balance,
       lag(balance) over (order by tran_date) as previous_balance
FROM min_balance
WHERE balance_rank = 1;
```

Comment: : This works a little better for me but I need to get data for those days that there is no transaction on.  Those days should have the same data as the previous data that do.  Is there anything else I need to do for that?  I did try several approaches but am failing hard.  For example, in above data, I should get 50 from Dec 1 to Dec 9, 130 from Dec 24 to Dec 31.  Basically, if there is no transaction on that day, should get carried overs from previous date that do have values.

Comment: I added another example which also selects the rows that "are not there"

Comment: : I didn't get the balance from the previous day, ie balance carried over.

Comment: I edited my answer to show a full solution. It's a bit longish, but should run on 8.4 as well

Comment: Thank you a_horse_with_no_name for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Ignore everything in that other answer.  That guy Malvolio is an blowhard and an idiot.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT MIN(balance), transaction_date FROM
( SELECT a.transaction_date, IFNULL(sum(b.deposit) - sum(b.withdrawal), 0) balance FROM transaction a
        LEFT JOIN transaction b ON a.seqno > b.seqno GROUP ON a.seqno
   UNION
  SELECT a.transaction_date, IFNULL(sum(b.deposit) - sum(b.withdrawal), 0) balance FROM transaction a
        LEFT JOIN transaction b ON a.seqno >= b.seqno GROUP ON a.seqno  ) x
GROUP BY transaction_date;
```

I was just about to fall asleep when this occurred to me.  The IFNULL may be a MySQL specific thing, but you can find a Postgres equivalent.

Comment: Nice idea ;) The standard function would be <code>coalesce</code> instead of IFNULL. But unfortunately this will not work on Postgres (or anything else apart from MySQL) because of the strange GROUP BY usage. In Postgres you would need to <code>GROUP BY a.transaction_date</code> instead of seqno but then it seems to return the wrong balance. At least with the sample data given (btw. it should be GROUP **BY** not GROUP ON in your example)

Comment: Yeah, some versions get upset if fail to group by a value that is not aggregated in the select, even if the value is on the same row as the group.  Just grouping by transaction date would give the min of the opening and closing balances.  You want both: `GROUP BY a.seqno, a.transaction_date`.  That should work find.  Sorry about the typo, it was 3 in the morning.  I just found out about COALESCE 5 minutes ago on another question.  I also realized it was unnecessary (though harmless) in the second query: there's no need to default to zero in the after-transaction balance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by minimum balance that you're talking about which you have less at, the start or the end of the day?

I suppose for each day you'd do something like this:

Balance from day before:

```
SELECT (SUM(deposit) - SUM(withdrawal)) WHERE date < [date you're after]
```

(not sure how date comparison would be done in PostgreSQL

Then:

```
SELECT (SUM(deposit) - SUM(withdrawal)) WHERE date = [date you're after]
```

Then whichever is greater.

If that's not what you meant, we need more info.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm going to assume that the transactions are *sequentially numbered*.  Just by definition, the transactions have to be properly ordered (because a $50 deposit followed by a $50 withdrawal on the same day would produce a very different answer from the same steps in a different order) and numbering them sequentially makes other things much easier.  Then we have to do some procedural handwaving:

```
CREATE TABLE running_total (seqno INT, transaction_date DATE, before NUMBER(10,20), after NUMBER(10,20);
SET tot=0;
FOR transaction IN SELECT * FROM transaction ORDER BY seqno ASC LOOP
    SET oldtot = tot;
    SET tot = tot = transaction.deposit - transaction.withdrawal;
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO running_total (seqno, transaction_date, before, after) VALUES (' ||
    transaction.seqno || ', ' || transaction.transaction_date || ',' || oldtot || ',' || tot || ')';
END LOOP;
```

(Forgive any typos -- I don't have PostGres handy).  Now we have a table with all the balances in it, we just have to dig it out.

```
SELECT MIN(balance), transaction_date FROM
( SELECT before as balance, transaction_date FROM running_total
   UNION
 SELECT after as balance, transaction_date FROM running_total) x 
GROUP BY transaction_date;
```

I can't test this here, but it should work.

Comment: : Yes, there is a tran_id in the table so the transactions are sequential in nature.  However, I do not have the permission to create a new table.  Is there another way to do this without creating a new table?

Comment: I hesitate to say it's impossible, but it's certainly extraordinary difficult.  Basically, if you have 10 transactions on 10 days, there are 110 different values to compute (each day's opening balance and the balance after each transaction), each one the result of up to 200 additions and subtractions.  I just don't see that happening without an intermediate table.  If you don't have `CREATE TABLE`, perhaps you have `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`.

Comment: the procedural part is not valid Postgres syntax. Additionally Postgres 8.4 does not support "anonymous" PL/pgSQL blocks. But creating the temporary table is not necessary at all as the running total can be generated using standard windowing functions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you number your transactions within a day, I took the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE transaction (
    tran_date date,
    num       int,
    withdraw  numeric,
    deposit   numeric
);

INSERT INTO transaction VALUES
    ('2010-11-23', 1,      0.00,      50.00),
    ('2010-12-10', 1,      0.00,      50.00),
    ('2010-12-10', 2,      0.00,     200.00),
    ('2010-12-12', 1,    100.00,       0.00),
    ('2010-12-20', 1,      0.00,      50.00),
    ('2010-12-20', 2,     70.00,       0.00),
    ('2010-12-20', 3,      0.00,      50.00),
    ('2010-12-20', 4,      0.00,      50.00),
    ('2010-12-24', 1,    150.00,       0.00);
```

Then, the following query appears to give you your answer:

```
WITH dates (tran_date) AS (SELECT date '2010-12-01' + generate_series(0, 30)),    
     transactions AS (SELECT tran_date, num,
                             coalesce(withdraw, 0) AS withdraw, 
                             coalesce(deposit, 0) AS deposit
                      FROM dates FULL OUTER JOIN transaction USING (tran_date)),
     running_totals AS (SELECT tran_date,     
                               sum(deposit - withdraw) OVER (ORDER BY tran_date, num ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS lagging_total,
                               sum(deposit - withdraw) OVER (ORDER BY tran_date, num ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS current_total
                        FROM transactions)
SELECT tran_date, min(least(lagging_total, current_total))
FROM running_totals
GROUP BY tran_date
HAVING tran_date IN (SELECT tran_date FROM dates)
ORDER BY tran_date;
```

Note, however, that you need PostgreSQL 9.0 for that because the `1 PRECEDING` clause is not supported in earlier versions.  If you can't upgrade, you will probably need some kind of procedural solution like the other answers suggest.

In any case I recommend writing unit tests for this. ;-)

Comment: why would you need the 1 preceeding? As far as I can tell the mininum balance can be calculated without it (See my last example)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Otherwise you only get the minimum balance on the day after the first transaction of the day. But here we also want to consider transactions up to the end of the previous day.

Comment: @But wouldn't that simply be the last balance of the previous day? Which could be referenced with `lag()` in 8.4 already

Comment: For the life of me, I can not find how to use the lag function.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a column to the database that tracks the current balance (calculated at each deposit/withdrawal). That way it would simply a case of returning the minimum for that column within the date range you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the help.  I've used the following to solve this.  I don't know how efficient the code is though.

```
select dt::date, 
coalesce(case when balance<=coAmt then balance else coAmt end, 
(select sum(coalesce(deposit, 0.00))-sum(coalesce(withdraw, 0.00)) 
from  where tran_date<=dt::date and acc_no='3'), 0.00) amt
from (
select tran_date, min(balance) balance, 
coalesce((select sum(coalesce(deposit, 0.00) - coalesce(withdraw, 0.00)) 
from transaction where tran_date<t.tran_date and acc_no=t.acc_no), 0.00) coAmt
from (
select tran_id, acc_no, tran_date, deposit, withdraw,
sum(deposite - withdraw) over (order by tran_id) balance 
from transaction sv group by tran_id, acc_no, tran_date, deposite, withdraw) t 
where acc_no='3' group by tran_date, acc_no order by tran_date ) t1 
right join 
generate_series('2010-12-01', '2010-12-31', interval '1 day') as dt on dt=tran_date 
group by dt, tran_date, balance, coAmt order by dt
```

Again, thanks for all your help.